# peaceful-warrior tag

Tags: support, tags, specific-question

[This question](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/69416/what-was-the-significance-of-two-different-shoes-wore-in-peaceful-warrior) and [this question](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/69417/what-is-the-significance-of-the-title-peaceful-warrior) have been tagged with [peacefulwarrior](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/peacefulwarrior). This new tag doesn't follow the tag naming policy (it should be [peaceful-warrior](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/peaceful-warrior)).

When I'm trying to correct it the following message appears:
[image]

Comment: Next time this happens, a flag is enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Done](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/peaceful-warrior).

Ba dum tss.